# Border Radius with background cannot work

Tags: android, html, css

I set the webview on Android 2.x browser. I want my button to have `border-radius` and `background-color`. I specify these values in CSS for both, however, it doesn't work.

When I set the values separately then it works.

Any ideas, why is it not working when I specify all values at once?

**html**

```
<button class="btn">click</button>
```

**css**

```
.btn{/*border radius does not work*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
    border-radius: 12px; 
    background-color:green;
}

.btn{/*works*/
    border-radius:12px;
}

.btn{/*works*/
    background-color:green;
}
```

[image: Button example]

Comment: The image, what you have provided, doesn't reflect your issue. You clearly have more code, so please provide all the code what is associated with `.btn` class and its parent classes.

Comment: If I were to take a wild guess, I'd say maybe you have errors in the CSS. Missing semicolons would do it. Style blocks with only one property don't require a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include overflow hidden and display:block

overflow:hidden;
display: block

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This should work on any Android starting from 1.6 as mentioned on [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/).

```css
button{
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    border-radius: 12px; 
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

As another option of designing a button in HTM5L and CSS3 would be to use `a` tag. Like so:

```css
a{
  background-color:green;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-border-radius:12px; 
  -moz-border-radius:12px; 
  border-radius:12px;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" alt="">click</a>
```

Or you can try using `<input>` tag of a `type="button"` or `type="submit"`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). Like so:

```css
input{
  background-color:green;
  -webkit-border-radius:12px;
  -moz-border-radius:12px; 
  border-radius:12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click">
<input type="submit" value="click">
```

If any of these methods does not work for you, then there is a high chance that other CSS or JavaScript settings are causing this. And, you will need to include additional code in your question.